# Corda VaultQuery on Column with Join

Tags: corda

Can vault query work with fields that are associated with column that contain List and annotated with `ElementCollection` and `CollectionTable` ?

Comment: Yes. You need to use `transaction_id` and `output_index` columns to joins two tables.

Comment: @BalajiMore I have already added those as part of the Join Column ,The column will have a List of String so target class I have set a String .  when I do a vault query on the particular field , I always get ` at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]` . I am using Builder.notIn over my FieldInfo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Here is the page for how to make Vault Query in Corda: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html

Comment: @BalajiMore I have already added those as part of the Join Column ,The column will have a List of String so target class I have set a String .  when I do a vault query on the particular field , I always get ` at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]` . I am using Builder.notIn over my FieldInfo

Comment: @prashants if you are using VaultQuery api than I think you don't need to worry about the join of ElementCollection, you can just write the builder query criteria and provide it to vaultquery.

Comment: @balajimore I feel there is a miscommunication here , I have already created whatever you have mentioned in your comment , In My comment to you I have posted the error that I am getting when I do a vault query on that Particular Field

Comment: @PeterLi I have already added those as part of the Join Column ,The column will have a List of String so target class I have set a String . when I do a vault query on the particular field , I always get ` at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]` . I am using Builder.notIn over my FieldInfo

Comment: @prashants I'm afraid I could help you here without having more info. It could be helpful if you share the schema definition and the query that you have build.